# Cordova application with local Javascript files - many files or just one?

Tags: javascript, cordova, minify

I am building a Cordova mobile application, and the custom scripts I am making are all locally inside the application package, and I am concerned about performance.
Is it ok for the files to be many, like each big namespace variable to be in a separate file, or should I put them all in one file?

Like I said, all of these files are going to be presented locally and not on a server, and I am concerned about the performance.

Comment: Usually there is a bundling handler, that joins all single files to a big one. So one can maintain the single files yet transmit one big file to the client. Yet it depends on your website overall if there is any noticable impact.

Comment: like I said this is not a website, but a Cordova mobile application, the javascript files will be presented locally on the device

Comment: I Agree with @Lain, as well as AndyLamb however I don't think Andy's answer should not have been more then a comment. If you want to improve performance, have a look at Gulp and bundle plugins. **Sidenote**: Cordova applications ARE websites running in a mobile app container. Nothing special there, except for a few JS actions you get to access stuff like the camera.

Comment: @Sartheris Stormhammer: Yes, I guessed so. That's why it is just a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't optimise for performance without first showing there is a performance problem and identifying exactly where the problem lies. Code for maintainability first. I'd keep your JavaScript files separate.

Comment: by performance I don't mean there are problems, but I do want everything to load as fast as possible

Comment: Don't aim for 'as fast as possible' when dealing with user interaction. Instead aim for 'fast enough' from the users' perspective. Being able to make changes quickly, safely, and therefore cheaply will be more valuable to you and your users in the long run.

Comment: I see, yes, but I want to hear other opinions as well, so not accepting the answer just yet

Answer (score 0):

Your app should have some sort of build process. There are lots of tools that help automate this process ([gulp](http://gulpjs.com), [grunt](http://gruntjs.com), etc.) but you can get by with simple npm scripts as well. *How* you create a build process is not the point here. The benefits, however, are many:

1. You can develop your app using multiple small files. If you have good organization and consistent naming practices, these files will be easier to maintain than one large file.
2. You can build appropriate debug and release versions of your app from those files.

   a. If you want the files to be bundled into one large file, you can use a packer like [Browserify](http://browserify.org), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or [JSPM](http://jspm.io). Then, depending on the options you pass, your debug version can include the necessary sourcemaps to make debugging easy.

   b. You might also want to use other tools, such as a minifier for your JS code, or image optimizer for your icons.
3. You can use the well-established module patterns to create modular code that doesn't pollute the global namespace (if you use something like Browserify, JSPM, etc.). This means you can do something like this:

   ```
   // file: say.js
   module.exports = {
       hello: function hello() {
           alert("hello");
       },
       goodbye: ...,
       ...
   };

   // file: index.js
   var say = require("./say.js");
   say.hello();
   say.goodbye();
   ```

Do none of the above because it will be "faster", though, because the difference when loading a single file vs loading multiple files is almost certainly negligible and on the order of milliseconds. Your user simply will not notice unless you've got a huge number of files. And should it become an issue, it's easy to make your build process generate a release version with everything bundled up into one large file without sacrificing maintainability.

Do *do* the above to make your workflow easier. Editing a single file with a hundred thousand lines is no fun -- you don't want to do that, trust me.